# How can I make "HP Laser 107a" printer work on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, printing

Recently I updated from 20.04 to 22.04.
When I found out the printer's not working anymore, I followed the advice given here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ipp-usb/+bug/1970055
, that is:

> sudo apt purge ipp-usb
> (=for 22.04)(for 20.04: sudo apt purge ippusbxd)
>
> wget https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/printers/CLP150/uld-hp_V1.00.39.12_00.15.tar.gz
>
> tar -xvf uld-hp_V1.00.39.12_00.15.tar.gz
>
> cd uld/
>
> sudo ./install.sh

but that didn't make it print, it seems I got it installed from the previous version. Do you have any ideas what else to try? I need to print for my daily functioning. Should I downgrade to 20.04?

Thank you for your time.

---

edit:
the output of

```
lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7
```

is:

```
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Bidirectional
      iInterface              0 
--
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      4 
      iInterface              0 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
--
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      4 
      iInterface              0 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
```

---

edit2:

Ok, i have typed `lpinfo -v` and `lpinfo -m` into terminal without problems, but  `lpadminn -p 107a -v "URI" -E -m PPD` results in:

> Command 'lpadminn' not found, did you mean:
> command 'lpadmin' from deb cups-client (2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1)
> Try: sudo apt install

So i tried `lpadmin -p 107a -v "URI" -E -m PPD` which says:

> lpadmin: Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS.
> lpadmin: Bad device-uri "URI".

The printer isn't working yet. Any ideas what else to try?

---

edit3:
`lpinfo -m` outsputs way more than i can enter here, and im lost when it comes to which of the lines to choose as a ppd, any ideas?

---

edit4:
so i got this answer:

> $ lpadmin -p 107a -v
> "usb://HP/Laser%20103%20107%20108?serial=CNB3PBS0W5" -E -m
> "uld-hp/HP_Laser_10x_Series.ppd HP Laser 10x Series" lpadmin: Printer
> drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of
> CUPS. lpadmin: cups-driverd failed to get PPD file - see error_log for
> details.

not sure how to find the exact error

Comment: Do note, if you upgrade a 20 system to 22 no user level packages change being a benefit of the *snap* only 20 & 22 systems; only the core of the OS. That is different from 20.04 when upgraded to 22.04 as on the *year.month* systems all packages (except *snap*) packages upgrade.  Your question mixes *snap* only & *deb* (+ *snap*) Ubuntu products, ie. 20 & 20.04 are different systems, just like 22.04 (released 2022-April) & 22 (released 2022-July) are different systems.  Please be precise with details.

Comment: You can clarify the behaviour of this device on Ubuntu and obtain a way forward by giving the output of `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I edited the question.

Comment: *Bad device-uri "URI".* You have not **substituted** for the URI  and PPD given by the previous two commands. The UR begins with *usb*,

Comment: Thank you!, i think i identified the URI, but im lost when it comes to PPD, there's so much output and i cant find anything saying smth like "Hp laser 107"

Comment: @laketax In the light of your *edit3:* I have added to my answer.

Comment: Regarding Edit 4; The PPD name starts at the beginning of the line and ends with **.ppd**.

Comment: oh my god thank you!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HP Laser 107a was first vended in about 2019. It is a USB-only printer. Such USB-only devices may or may not understand the IPP-over-USB protocol, as almost all modern network devices are known to do.

The `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7` twice shows

> bInterfaceClass         7
> bInterfaceSubClass      1 Prier
> bInterfaceProtocol      4

The 7/1/4 sequence indicates a printer that claims to understand the IPP-over-USB protocol and it should be capable of being dealt with by Ubuntu 2.04 without fuss,

Unfortunately, it is known that the **claim is [spurious](https://github.com/OpenPrinting/ipp-usb/issues/51)**.

The device has be set up with a URI and PPD in the traditional way. The CUPS web interface or system-config-printer could be used. I would get the URY with `lpinfo -v` and the PPD with `lpinfo -m` and use `lpadmin -p 107a -v "URI" -E -m PPD`.

`lpinfo -m` by itself gives copious output, so it is best to narrow down the PPD possibilities with a search for **10x**.

```
lpinfo -m | grep 10x
```

It is assumed that

**uld-hp_V1.00.39.12_00.15.tar.gz**

has been installed correctly. This printer is not supported by HPLIP.